# Python not identifying a white space character

Tags: python, regex

I am near my wit's end with this problem: Basically, I need to remove a double space gap between words. My program happens to be in Hebrew, but this is the basic idea:

```
TITLE: הלכות ‏ ‏השכמת‏ ‏הבוקר‏
```

Notice there is an extra space between the first two words (Herbew reads right to left).

I tried many, many different methods, here are a few:

```
# tried all these with and without unicode
title = re.sub(u'\s+',u' ',title.decode('utf-8'))
title = title.replace("  "," ")
title = title.replace(u"  הלכות",u" הלכות")
```

Until finally I resorted to making a very unnecessary method (some of the formatting got messed up when pasting):

```
def remove_blanks(s):
    word_list = s.split(" ")
    final_word_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        print "word: " +word
        #tried every qualifier I could think of...
        if not_blank(word) and word!=" " and True != re.match("s*",word):
            print "^NOT BLANK^"
            final_word_list.append(word)
    return ' '.join(final_word_list)

def not_blank(s):
    while " " in s:
        s = s.replace(" ","")
    return (len(s.replace("\n","").replace("\r","").replace("\t",""))!=0);
```

And, to my utter amazement, this is what I got back:

```
word: הלכות
^NOT BLANK^
word: ‏           #this should be tagged as Blank!!
^NOT BLANK^
word: ‏השכמת‏
^NOT BLANK^
word: ‏הבוקר‏
^NOT BLANK^
```

So apparently my qualifier didn't work. What is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you print the word's `repr`?  `print "word: ", repr(word)`?  It's possible that you have a unicode space -- e.g.  ['NO-BREAK SPACE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)

Comment: There's at least one invisible character between the spaces. I don't know what that character is, but it's what's causing your confusion.

Comment: If the pasted content can be believed, you have a ['RIGHT-TO-LEFT-MARK'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) sitting between some of your spaces.

Comment: @mgilson thanks for the tip. I tried repr(word) and for the blank space I got this: '\xe2\x80\x8f'. It's actually in the beginning of every string. Looked it up: \xe2\x80\x8e, LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK

Answer (score 0):

There was a hiding \xe2\x80\x8e, LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK. Found it using repr(word). Thanks @mgilson!